# OnCollisionEnter not working, What is wrong?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Help, im using unity 2020.3.15f2, OnCollisionEnter is not working.

I have 2 gameObjects, both with not trigger SphereColliders and not Kinematic RigidBodies.

My RigidBodies doesn´t have gravity on, but they have constants (don´t move on z, and don´t rotate on x or y)

Im shure they collide because both gameobjects interact colliding, but when i call the script that contains the OnCollisionEnter (that just call a Debug.Log("Collision")) i don´t see anything on console.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col){
  Debug.Log("Collision"); //i don´t see anything on console
}
```

This is my SphereCollider and RigidBody setup for both GameObjects:

[image]

And the script is on the parent of those GameObjects, like this:

[This is the Scene Hierarcy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj1vO.png)

[And this is the "Element" Hierarchy (note: i edit it to mantain the names of my gameobjects in secret its my boss desition)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4BBT.png)

[As you can see here the "Element" its the one who have the script with the OnCollisionEnter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21pxA.png)

Comment: Just to be sure: your `OnCollisionEnter` script is attached to the same object as the collider and Rigidbody?

Comment: Any chance your game is 2d?

Comment: I can't reproduce the observed problem with the code & setup in the question. Please edit the question to include a [mre]. For Unity debugging questions this means enough information to produce the problem starting from an empty/new project. My best guesses are that there is a compile error elsewhere in the code preventing the `OnCollisionError` from being compiled, or that the MonoBehaviour with the above `OnCollisionEnter` is attached to a descendant of the gameobject with Collider rather than an ancestor or the gameobject iteself.

Comment: From an empty project, create a sphere. position at 0,0,0 add a rigidbody, disable gravity, add freeze position z and freeze rotation xy. copy and paste sphere to create sphere B. position sphere b at 0,-5,0. Add following script to sphere A: `public class test : MonoBehaviour { private void Start() { GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.down; } void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) { Debug.Log("Collision"); }}`. Run & see that log appears.

Comment: Yes, my OnCollisionEnter script is attached to the same object as the collider and Rigidbody, in fact, both of my gameObjects have it.

My game is not 2d, it works like 2d, but i used sphere collider and Rigidbody (not Rigidbody2d or circle collider)

Comment: yes @Ruzihm, It detects the collision

Comment: I forgot menction: the gameObjects that are colliding are children of a parent, that parent have the script with the OnCollisionEnter, i think thats the problem

Comment: the question should be edited to include the steps needed to reproduce the problem. that includes how to set up the hierarchy and components.

Comment: I don´t have enougth reputation to edit :,v

but i think i found the answer

Comment: This [edit link above](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70127580/edit) doesn't let you edit? o_O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solve by thinking: How my scene is setted?, I see that the gameObjects that contain the Collider and the RigidBody, are child of the gameObject with the OnCollisionEnter script.

Aparently, OnCollisionEnter only works with the gameObject itself, if the script is attached to a parent or to a child of the gameObject, it´ll not work.

So with that, i just need to make a Collision Detection Script on the gameObjects with the Colliders, and entangle it with the parent´s script to do... the thinks the gameObject should do when collide.

Thanks all for your feedback and help, special thanks for @derHugo and @Ruzhim who are the people who help me to detect that problem.

Solution: make shure the script with the OnCollisionEnter is on the gameObject that have the Collider and the RigidBody, not the parent, not the child.